# Default generic parameter

Tags: rust, traits

I have a struct that we can construct with the builder pattern because there are some `Option`al fields.

If I use the builder functions to specify these optional fields, I don't have to specify the generic parameters.

But if I don't call these functions, I need to specify the generic parameters.

Here is an example:

```
use Structs::*;

struct Struct<T, F: Fn(T)> {
    func: Option<F>,
    value: T,
}

enum Structs<T, F: Fn(T)> {
    Struct1(T),
    Struct2(T, F),
}

impl<T, F: Fn(T)> Struct<T, F> {
    fn new(value: T) -> Struct<T, F> {
        Struct {
            func: None,
            value: value,
        }
    }

    fn build(self) -> Structs<T, F> {
        if let Some(func) = self.func {
            Struct2(self.value, func)
        }
        else {
            Struct1(self.value)
        }
    }

    fn func(mut self, func: F) -> Struct<T, F> {
        self.func = Some(func);
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _strct = Struct::new(42)
        .func(|n| { println!("{}", n); })
        .build();

    //let _strct = Struct::new(42).build(); // Does not compile.
    let _strct = Struct::<_, &Fn(_)>::new(42).build();
}
```

I would like to omit the type annotation when the optional fields are not set, like so:

```
let _strct = Struct::new(42).build();
```

It should be specified that the `F` type depends on `T`.

I tried specifying a default type parameter as such:

```
impl<T, F: Fn(T) = Box<Fn(T)>> Struct<T, F> {
```

but it does not solve the issue.

So how can I avoid having to specify the type parameters in the `Struct::new()` call?

If it is not possible to avoid this, is there any alternatives to the builder pattern that would allow me to omit the type annotation?

Comment: If you don't specify a concrete type for `T` or `F`, then how much space should the Rust compiler allocate to store `Struct`?

Comment: @Shepmaster, in theory, if the compiler can determine that `F` is never used it can just write that field as size 0. The problem, of course, is that this sort of whole-program inference is really complicated.

Comment: @Jsor an interesting point, but as you mention, Rust doesn't do any inference beyond a single function boundary.

Comment: @Shepmaster can you elaborate or give some references about the affirmation "Rust doesn't do any inference beyond a single function boundary"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following [Francis Gagné's clever solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37313316/155423), here's a similar idea that can work on stable Rust:

```
struct Struct<T, F: Fn(T)> {
    func: Option<F>,
    value: T,
}

enum Structs<T, F: Fn(T)> {
    Struct1(T),
    Struct2(T, F),
}

impl<T> Struct<T, fn(T)> {
    fn new(value: T) -> Struct<T, fn(T)> {
        Struct {
            func: None,
            value: value,
        }
    }
}

impl<T, F: Fn(T)> Struct<T, F> {
    fn func<F2: Fn(T)>(self, func: F2) -> Struct<T, F2> {
        Struct {
            func: Some(func),
            value: self.value,
        }
    }

    fn build(self) -> Structs<T, F> {
        use Structs::*;

        if let Some(func) = self.func {
            Struct2(self.value, func)
        } else {
            Struct1(self.value)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _strct = Struct::new(42)
        .func(|n| {
            println!("{}", n);
        })
        .build();

    let _strct = Struct::new(42).build();
}
```

Instead of a clear `Void` type, we simply say that we return a struct that would be parameterized for a function pointer. You could likewise specify a reference trait object:

```
impl<T> Struct<T, &'static Fn(T)> {
    fn new(value: T) -> Struct<T, &'static Fn(T)> {
```

Answering my own question from a comment:

> If you don't specify a concrete type for `T` or `F`, then how much space should the Rust compiler allocate to store `Struct`?

The size of a `fn()` is 8 bytes on a 64-bit machine, leading to a total of 16 bytes for the entire structure:

```
std::mem::size_of::<fn()>();
std::mem::size_of_val(&strct);
```

However, when you give it a concrete callback, the structure only takes 8 bytes! That's because the type will be monomorphized for the callback, which needs no state and can basically be inlined.

Francis Gagné's solution only requires 8 bytes in each case, as the `Void` type has a size of zero!

Comment: In theory, a `Struct<T, Void>` could be even further optimized: since the `Some` variant of an `Option<Void>` cannot be instantiated, only the `None` variant remains. An enum with a single variant doesn't need a discriminant (though right now, it appears that there's still a discriminant for a unit enum), and since `None` doesn't hold any data, then the size of an `Option<Void>` could be zero. Thus, the size of a `Struct<i32, Void>` would be 4 rather than 8.

Answer (score 9):

There's a way to solve this by changing the type of the builder as it evolves. Since `Struct::func` takes ownership of the builder and returns a new builder, we are free to change the result type.

First, we need to specify an initial type for `F`. We could just choose any existing implementation for `Fn(T)`, but we can do better. I propose that we use an [empty/void/uninhabited/bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type), so that it's clear that when `F` is that type, then the `Option` is `None` (you can't construct a `Some(x)` because there's no valid `x` for an empty type). One downside to this approach is that implementing `Fn`, `FnMut` and `FnOnce` for types (other than closures) is unstable and requires a nightly compiler.

```
#![feature(fn_traits)]
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]

enum Void {}

impl<T> FnOnce<T> for Void {
    type Output = ();

    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, _args: T) {
        match self {}
    }
}

impl<T> FnMut<T> for Void {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, _args: T) {
        match *self {}
    }
}

impl<T> Fn<T> for Void {
    extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, _args: T) {
        match *self {}
    }
}
```

Next, let's move `Struct::new` to a different `impl` block:

```
impl<T> Struct<T, Void> {
    fn new(value: T) -> Struct<T, Void> {
        Struct {
            func: None,
            value: value,
        }
    }
}
```

This `impl` is *not* generic on `F`: `new` will only ever generate a `Struct` where `F = Void`. This avoids ambiguities in the case where `func` is never called.

Finally, we need to make `func` change the type of the builder:

```
impl<T, F0: Fn(T)> Struct<T, F0> {
    fn func<F1: Fn(T)>(self, func: F1) -> Struct<T, F1> {
        Struct {
            func: Some(func),
            value: self.value,
        }
    }
}
```

This method needs to stay in an `impl` block that is generic over the `F` type parameter on `Struct<T, F>`, so that it can be used on a builder on which `func` was already called. However, `func` must also be generic itself so that it can receive any type of function (rather than a function matching the type of the builder). Then, instead of mutating `self`, we have to construct a new `Struct`, because we can't just coerce a `Struct<T, F0>` into a `Struct<T, F1>`.